# Vue.js + Spring Boot + PayPal

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js, paypal

I want to add PayPal to my existing Vue.js + Spring Boot Project.
I googled, but did not find anything.
Do you have a tutorial or any suggest how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the PayPal documentation**

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/

**Here is what to search on youtube**

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=paypal+api+tutorial&page&utm_source=opensearch

Comment: Well, how do I connect the Frontend Vue.js with the Backend API together?

Comment: I have never done it before but I would advice reading their document